# What is the meaning of this: return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the meaning of the "return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener" in the code below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_home)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_dashboard)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_notifications)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }
}
```

Comment: Return with label means that you are specifically saying that I want to return from this methods, since calling return will only return from the nearest inclosing function

Answer (score 1):

From the Kotlin documentation:

```
fun foo() {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach lit@{
        if (it == 3) return@lit // local return to the caller of the lambda, i.e. the forEach loop
        print(it)
    }
    print(" done with explicit label")
}
```

> The return-expression returns from the nearest enclosing function, i.e. foo. (Note that such non-local returns are supported only for lambda expressions passed to inline functions.) If we need to return from a lambda expression, we have to label it and qualify the return:

[See more here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels)